# Create, read, and erase cookies with jQuery

Tags: jquery, cookies

Somebody help me. How to create, read and erase some cookies with jQuery ?

Answer (score 377):

Use [JavaScript Cookie plugin](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)

#### Set a cookie

```
Cookies.set("example", "foo"); // Sample 1
Cookies.set("example", "foo", { expires: 7 }); // Sample 2
Cookies.set("example", "foo", { path: '/admin', expires: 7 }); // Sample 3
```

#### Get a cookie

```
alert( Cookies.get("example") );
```

#### Delete the cookie

```
Cookies.remove("example");
Cookies.remove('example', { path: '/admin' }) // Must specify path if used when setting.
```

Comment: @RameshSoni, I tried to use this plugin with rails, but it is not working for me. Any idea if there are issues with this and Rails 4? Thanks

Comment: @jackerman09 well this is client side plugin which works with jQuery. Doesn't matter if you are using rails. Could you provide more details on your issue?

Comment: @RameshSoni, I was specifically referring to the https://github.com/RyanScottLewis/jquery-cookie-rails, which I realize you aren't specifically alluding to above, but when I include it in my Gemfile and application.js (immediately after //= require jQuery, as the installation instructions say to do), I get an error whenever I load the app about missing files. If I remember correctly, the error was something like "Sprockets::FileNotFound" (or something close to that, I'm not at my dev computer right now). Thanks!

Comment: there is a newer version here https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie, the API is a little different

Comment: not working in laravel as well

Comment: Native javascript provides a very simple way to access Cookies without jQuery, hope this help
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
e.g. `document.cookie`

Answer (score 137):

As I know, there is no direct support, but you can use plain-ol' javascript for that:

```js
// Cookies
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";               

    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```

You can access like below,

```
createCookie("test","test",1); // to create new cookie

readCookie("test"); // to retrive data from cookie

eraseCookie("test"); // will delete that cookie
```

Comment: i have been use this script, but doesn't work

Comment: @Agus ... works fine here, I have it in production projects and they work like a charm! what error are you getting?

Comment: Good ol javascript is the base of jQuery! This is the same code in many plugins. +1

Comment: Cross-browser correctness is a constant problem with web development. Are cookies handled uniformly enough to directly use document.cookie everywhere? Can you say which browsers this has been tested with?

Comment: Works OK on Opera 29, Firefox 38, Chrome 42. IE 11 not working.

Comment: Best answer for this question, & easy to use

Comment: @AgusPuryanto, you need to access via createCookie("test","test",1);

Answer (score 11):

Use jquery cookie plugin, the link as working today:
https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Answer (score 5):

Google is my friend and it showed me this page:

- http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/
- [How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)
- [Can jQuery read/write cookies to a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95213/can-jquery-read-write-cookies-to-a-browser)

Comment: downvoted for being a 'smartiepants' answer.

Comment: "Provide context for links - Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer