# Use a cookie value in a getJson call

Tags: javascript, json, cookies, cfc

I want to use a getJson call like this"

```
$.getJSON("cfc/getMember.cfc?method=getUser&returnformat=json&queryFormat=column",{"memberID":userID}, function(res,code)
```

the userID is stored as a cookie - so I thought I'd simply use:

```
function checkCookie(){ 
 var userID=getCookie("UID");
}
```

Now (as I'm sure you cal tell) I'm new to javascript so that might be my problem - but I'm after some advice on how to use a cookie value in the getJSON call.

Thanks!

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `getCookie()` function is already defined and correctly retrieves your cookies, then all you need to do is define the `userID` before you make the call to $.getJSON:

```
var userID=getCookie("UID");
$.getJSON("cfc/getMember.cfc?method=getUser&returnformat=json&queryFormat=column", {"memberID":userID}, function(res,code) {});
```

Comment: Thanks Calvin - I've got var userID=getCookie("uid"); as part of the check cookie function - are you saying I need to repeat it? Thanks.

Comment: For how to use jQuery to get cookie: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599287/create-read-and-erase-cookies-with-jquery

Comment: @Simon, no you simply need to declare your `userID` variable before you call the `$.getJSON()` method, so that you're not inserting an undeclared variable as "memberID".