# how to check a php cookie is set or not in jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am developing w php web site. Here I have set a php cookie

```
 setcookie('hotelId',$resHotel);
```

I want to check whether it’s set or not using jquery or javascript. I have used the following code

```
if($.cookie('hotelId')) {
        alert("yes");
    };
```

But it's not working

Is there is any way to find PHP cookie is exist or not in jquery

Thanks

Comment: related : [stackoverflow.com/questions/1599287/...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599287/create-read-and-erase-cookies-with-jquery)

Comment: No, My question is " How to check a 'php' cookie is exist or not using jquery ". I don't have the jquery cookie, i have php cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work if these two conditions are met:

- you have installed the [extra library](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) that you need to use `$.cookie()`
- you have called `setcookie()` before outputting any part of your html

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have the right libraries loaded into the page? I don't think cookie behavior is included with jQuery by default.

You can view cookies manually easily. The method varies a little from browser to browser, but (in Firefox, for example) if you go to Preferences > Privacy > remove individual cookies, you can browse through them and see their contents. This can help you debug whether your php code is setting the cookie as desired.

Answer (score 0):

First get the specified cookie as follows

```
var cookie=$.cookie("set");
if(!cookie)
{
   $.cookie("set","foo"); //if there is no cookie set it
}
```