# pass values between two different pages using Jquery

Tags: jquery

can any one tell me how to do this in JQuery?

i have two .aspx pages named default1.aspx and default2.aspx. default1.aspx has one textbox named as textbox1 and default2.aspx has one textbox named as textbox2. default1.aspx opens the default2.aspx by using window.showmodaldialog(). Issue is that While i am changing the text of textbox2, the textbox1 text also gets changed.

Comment: any fiddle or jQuery code disturbing you would be useful, try posting here.

Answer (score 1):

one possible way to do it using cookies

check it here

[Create, read, and erase cookies with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599287/create-read-and-erase-cookies-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

another way to do this if you is to use html5 webstorage

firstpage

```
localStorage.value="value";
```

secondpage

```
var value=localStorage.value;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp