# PHP Cookies not working

Tags: php, cookies

I am building a website with logins. I have sessions working fine but I need to be able to keep them logged in if the click remember me. Currently I have the login script saving a cookie with the Username and Password they type to some cookies. I the below script $username and $password are set higher in the script. The $_SESSION variables are getting set fine. And I know the script is going into the if statement because before I place a alert box in there.

login.php

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getLoginResults))
{
    $error = "Login Successful";
    $_SESSION['Username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['Password'] = $_POST['password'];
    if($keep == 1)
    {
        setcookie("Username", $username, time()+3600*24*30);
        setcookie("Password", $password, time()+3600*24*30);
    }
}
```

When I check the login, I have a javascript alert so I knoe the cookie is set but the alert box is coming up empty.

check_login.php

```
echo "<script>alert('".$_COOKIE['Username']."')</script>";
```

What am I missing???

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but do not do this, ever! Storing the password in a cookie is a cardinal sin. You should read up on how to deal with sessions the right way (with a session ID)

Comment: The username and password is not the actual one, its only what the user types in.

Comment: Why do you think you should store this in a cookie?

Comment: Re your specific problem, my suspicion would be the cookies are never set. Are you 1000% sure your condition is ever fulfilled and the lines setting the cookies ever run? You could do a test output (just an `echo "something";` really) to find out.

Comment: " its only what the user types in" So, it's the user's password, correct?

Comment: Pekka yes I placed an alert box in there before to test it.

Comment: Ok I'm getting a lot of flak for doing it this way, how else do I keep the user logged in when I am not hosting the site myself so I don't have control over the GC

Comment: $username and $password are not defined. Maybe you meant to set those as $_SESSION['Username'] and $_SESSION['Password']?

Comment: @TomHanson What's GC?

Comment: The normal approach is to have a database table that keeps track of which session ID successfully logged in when. To find out whether a user is logged in, you take his session ID, look whether there's an entry for it in the table, and when the user's last activity was. (You want the login to expire eventually so you can't reuse a days-old session)

Comment: GC = Garbage Collector aka when the session is removed

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using setcookie with a a path specified, this used to catch me out, as it assumes the current path by default. Using / will make the cookie work for the whole domain

```
setcookie("Username", $username, time()+3600*24*30, '/');
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked great. I thank you for answering with attacking me on my coding. I'm a new coder. For all the rest who commented... I will look into placing it in a table in the database

Comment: I don't think anyone is trying to attack you, they are just trying to help by alerting you to the security implications.

Answer (score 2):

You are writing a script code with PHP. PHP can only know the data that is sent with the request.

If you first set a cookie and then fetch data from `$_COOKIE`, the data is not yet there. First the browser must accept the cookie, and then send it back on the next request.

If you use Javascript instead and fetch the documents cookies from the browser, it would work.

#### And now the disclaimer

Never ever store the login credentials (username and password) as plain text in permanent cookies!

If done right, you create a long random string from a cryptographically secure random number generator (that means you do NOT use `rand()` or `mt_rand()`), store it in the cookie, and also in the database. This random string now is a replacement for username and password when it comes to checking credentials.

Comment: Thank you for writing this in a non abusive way. :D I am storing the password after it is crypted, is that ok?

Comment: The fetching of the cookie is inside a different script to the setting.

Comment: No, that is also not ok, because you are giving away the info of how your passwords are hashed - and if someone steals your database with usernames and hashes, he can instantly use the hashes to log in, because the hash is in the remember-me cookie. **Do not roll your own security mechanism**

Comment: Ok thanks for that, I will fix this up asap. The websites not live yet so I have time. :D

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `$keep` came from nowhere. If you used a checkbox for `$keep` variable, you can do the following.

```
<?
$keep = isset($_POST['keep']);
if ($keep) {
    .... // cookie set up
}
?>
```

Comment: He probably has keep defined above the loop. Aside that, don't open php with just <? - use <?PHP

Comment: Sorry for off topic but why ``<?PHP`` is preferable to ``<?``? Could you give me SO link discussing that?

Comment: @Kita - some servers dont have it enabled

Comment: The discussion is here: [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/200640)

Comment: <? can be interpreted as xml for one

Comment: @relentless but have you ever actually seen such a server in real life? I haven't. (But yeah, I guess if you want to build portable software, there's no way around long tags)

Comment: @Pekka웃 - Yep, once. It's a rare case and probably only valid if you're distributing code.

Comment: @Kai that doesn't make sense - when the HTML is output, any mention of a PHP ´<?` will have been parsed out. The problem is the other way round - the PHP parser will try to interpret XML `<?`s and cause trouble

Comment: Just regurgitating. I've never seen anyone defend the use of <? but everyone backs <?php. nothing wrong with holding conventions

Comment: PSR-1 standard, paragraph 2.1: "PHP code MUST use the long `<?php ?>` tags or the short-echo `<?= ?>` tags; it MUST NOT use the other tag variations."

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use Jquery/Javascript to set cookie in browser. I find it easier in jquery than PHP.

[Create, read, and erase cookies with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599287/create-read-and-erase-cookies-with-jquery)

Answer (score -1):

See How cookie works

index.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Himel Sarkar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php 


    setcookie("username","Himel Sarkar",time()+100);




    echo "This cookie is valied for 100 sec ";

     ?>
    <a href="welcome.php">Next Page</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

welcome.php

```
    <?php 

    echo $_COOKIE['username']."<br>";

     ?>
     <h4> If you go previous page then new cookie will genarate  <a href="index.php">Previous Page</a></h4>
```