# Session without duration

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) { 
  echo $_SESSION["name"] ;
}else{
   $_SESSION["name"] = 'Test';
   echo 'Just inserted: '.$_SESSION["name"] ;
}
```

I expect that only the first time it shows "Just inserted: Test" and then it should shows only "Test".

But on my server it **always** display "Just inserted: Test".

Can someone tell me why ?

**EDIT:**

New code:

```
var_dump(session_start());
var_dump(session_name()); 
var_dump(session_id());


if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) { 
  echo $_SESSION["name"] ;
}else{
   $_SESSION["name"] = 'Test';
   echo 'Just inserted: '.$_SESSION["name"] ;
}

phpinfo();
```

Comment: On your server or on your local machine?

Comment: Then try to check if session can be started. by doing `var_dump(session_start());`

Comment: I don't understand why this code is not working for you. Its working for me.

Comment: @MuntashirAkon This works for everyone. He has issues with php.ini on server machine

Comment: Try `phpinfo();` and find `session`

Comment: Everything seems to be perfect. When we call `session_start()` php automatically set a cookie to the browser (called `PHPSESSID`). But in your case, there wasn't any cookie at all. Try `var_dump(session_start());` instead of just `session_start()`. It should return `bool(true)`.

Comment: But it still didn't save any cookies. Try this `var_dump(session_name());` & this `var_dump(session_id());`. The first one should return session name and the second one should return session id.

Comment: Ok, this is the last comment. Try this `setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+3600);` after `session_start()`. This should set the cookie which is for some peculiar reasons not working.

Comment: It's working on our machine as you expected. Could you please tell me the session information from your phpinfo?

Comment: So, the problem is not with `session` at all but with cookie. Try one of these: [PHP - setcookie(); not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316870/php-setcookie-not-working) Or [PHP – setcookie() not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662580/php-setcookie-not-working) or [PHP Cookies not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19260793/php-cookies-not-working)

Comment: @MuntashirAkon ok thanks :)

Comment: check out the value of session.gc_maxlifetime() in your php.ini

Comment: Try following line into your php.ini file:
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 24*60*60);

I think this might work for you, hope so...