# send data from page to page using ajax without server interaction html

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, json

I want to send json object from page 1 to page 2 without server interaction what i have tried so far is like this

from page 1 i have this code

```
url = '../reports/page2.php?basicinfo=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(basicinfo));
window.open(url + "&month=" + month, '_self');
```

in page two i acces the data by getting the object from the url.
But i had a problem. I exceeded the `The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.` So i wanted to try if it is possible using ajax what i have tried is

`var url = '../reports/page2.php;`
`var basicinfo = JSON.stringify(basicinfo)`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        action: "page2",basicinfo:'basicinfo '

    },
    complete: function() {
        window.location = url;
    }
});
```

I was directed to the correct page my problem is i cant get the data now.

Comment: Can you give sample or link to a good tutorial on how to do it

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/blog/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

Comment: Do i need to delete the saved data?i dont want my data to linger in the local storage i think it is not safe am i right?

Comment: you want to transfer data from one page to other and don't to user server for this and you don't even want to save it in jquery variable Then the only possible way is by using cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose You can use localstorage save your json in localstorage variable and fetch it at any moment

```
localStorage.setItem('favoriteflavor','vanilla'); /*how to save data in localstorage*/
var taste = localStorage.getItem('favoriteflavor');/*how to fetch data from localstorage*/
alert(taste);
localStorage.removeItem('favoriteflavor');/*how to delete data from localstorage*/
```

For more details click [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/blog/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/)

So save all your json in localstorage variable before

```
window.location = url;
```

in your `ajax` `complete` section and fetch `localstorage` data after redirection (i.e. on this page `url` )

If you don't want to use jquery variable for data security. Then the only possible way is by using cookies.
Here is the link on stack from where you can see how to create cookies using jquery [how to save data in a cookie using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20877142/how-to-save-data-in-a-cookie-using-jquery)

Comment: also there will be chance that the computer will be flooded with saved data in local storage?im sorry i am not sure how local storage work will the data in local storage be deleted automatically?

Comment: not automatically, but you can delete localstorage data when it is no longer needed by using `localStorage.removeItem();`

Comment: give me a minute sir i will try it out i will be back after a few minutes

Comment: i think i can work on the idea thank you so much on the idea my problem with be on how to delete the data in localStorage lol

Comment: One question why when i run for the first time the local storage doesnt save it

Comment: You can delete local storage data by using this `localStorage.removeItem('your_localstorage_variable_name');`

Comment: You will get data in localstorage if it is set

Answer (score 0):

Try to write this to a file and read from the popup.
`http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php`
`http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php`

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is stateless protocol. When you redirected to another page - it is new request and data from previous page will be lost. 
To share data between pages need to store data (from first ajax request), e.g in session, and restore data from session on second page.