# Stay on selected language when page refresh or move to another page

Tags: javascript, function, var

I found a reference for multi language for my website without using php. I had 2 languages: english & bahasa. Default is english when I choose bahasa and i refresh the page, it's back to english again as I want it to stay on the selected language

I couldn't figure out anyway as I'm still learning about jQuery and others.

```
changeLanguage("en");

$("#id_button").click(function(){
    changeLanguage("id");
});

$("#eng_button").click(function(){
    changeLanguage("en");
});
```

I expect that when I select bahasa dan when the page refresh or move to other pages, it will remain on my selected language.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cookie to store the language using Jquery

```
  $.cookie('lang','en');
```

To retrieve the data

```
  var current_language = $.cookie('lang');
```

For more reference please visit the link 
https://github.com/jaaulde/cookies#With_jQuery

and also someone answered this

[how to save data in a cookie using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20877142/how-to-save-data-in-a-cookie-using-jquery)