# how to remove cookie in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

cookie plugin .i m able to set the cookie but i am unable to delete the cookie.here is the code
i set cookie like
`var cookieValue = $.cookie("username",email,{ path: '/' ,domain:'serverurl'});` 
and i tried to remove cookie in my logout.html like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function session()
      {
      $.removeCookie("username", { path: '/' ,domain:'serverurl'});

      window.location="login.html"
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="session();"></body>
```

Comment: check these link which is answered in stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599287/create-read-and-erase-cookies-with-jquery

Comment: i tried but still the cookie are not removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
$.removeCookie('the_cookie', { path: '/' });
```