# How to get a cookie value for input field?

Tags: php, jquery, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

I have a form and I have set cookies to the input fields. I can find the cookies in `resources` when I go to `inspect element`. The code is confidential so I can't show how I set my cookies. But I am sure that I can find the selected input fields in resources->cookie.

The same form appears in all the pages. When I redirect from one page to other page the form fields which I selected must appear in all the pages.

I used  the below code for getting the cookie value

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if(input1 = getCookie("input1 "))
            document.myform.input1.value = input1 ;
    });
</script>
```

but I am getting error as `Uncaught ReferenceError: getCookie is not defined`

Can anyone suggest what would be the reason for this error? and how do I get the get cookie value to the input field?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599287/create-read-and-erase-cookies-with-jquery

Comment: most likely the same function used in this site http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you should google it how to set cookie, not sure if you declare the function as something like getCookie?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setCookie(key, value) {
        var expires = new Date();
        expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
    }

    function getCookie(key) {
        var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + key + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
        return keyValue ? keyValue[2] : null;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        setCookie("input1",'1');
        alert(getCookie("input1"));
        document.myform.input1.value = getCookie("input1");
    });

</script>
```

And Here is the Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hr4mubsw/5/

For more information check this one [How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

Hope it may help :)

Comment: from where do you get 'key' here in the function getCookie(key)

Comment: Actually key is what the parameter in that whatever created cookie name should come, I edited not if you see the edited ans you may know how it works. If you try the above code it will work.