# Set/unset cookie the simples way jquery-cookie

Tags: jquery, html, cookies

I i have a button which show/hide a div on onClick event. I want to remeber the state, on click keep div hidden for one day (set cookie which expires) and on another click keep div showed (delete cookie).

I need remember this state on whole domain.

What is the easiest way?
I´am the beginner, I prefer jquery-cookie - it is possible to use?
I can´t find any example where is this explained on onClick event.

Thanks alot!

Comment: you want button click event right?

Comment: curenttly for other functions for the button I have:$('#show_container_2').click(function() .....

Comment: would please share the html Tag for your Div

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bqwk8hg1/ (sorry for missing CSS)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bqwk8hg1/1/ check its div hide/unhide working for me

Comment: its ok, but how to set and unset the cookie?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bqwk8hg1/3/ Try it

Comment: It is still not functional

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-do-i-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin.

The documentation is just [here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#usage).

Here's an example in jsfiddle on how to use it (set cookie / unset cookie / display cookie) : http://jsfiddle.net/rdtome/73vzD/239/

(See the lines) :

```
$.cookie('test_cookie', 'hello cookie !'); // SET cookie
$.removeCookie('test_cookie'); // DELETE cookie
$.cookie('test_cookie'); // GET cookie
```

Comment: I have seen this link - but I donť know how to use it on onClick event with button. I need I simple example with functional solution.

Comment: Have a look at the jsfiddle in the answer. Also here : http://jsfiddle.net/rdtome/73vzD/239/

Answer (score 0):

Please find the URL for Better way cookie management.
[Create, read, and erase cookies with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599287/create-read-and-erase-cookies-with-jquery)

OR

```
for set cookie:
    $.cookie('cookieName', 'value', { expires: 7 });
for read cookie:
    $.cookie('the_cookie');

for Delete cookie:// set nulll for delete
    $.cookie('the_cookie', null);
```

for more information.
http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/jquery-cookies-get-set-and-delete.html

Comment: Thanks, but too complicated for me.

Comment: @RASAE, you want button click event with disable and enable cookie right?