# JQuery checkbox and uncheck using if and else function - unable to get it working

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

Can one kindly help me. I'm very new to jQuery.

- i have a checkbox with an id `#userj_neednotice`

> what i want to do is:

- when a user ticks the checkbox, the content with the class `.check_box_notice_content` should show
- when the user unchecks the box, the content with the class `.check_box_notice_content` should hide
- when the user has ticked the check box with the id `#userj_neednotice` and the page is refreshed and the checkbox is still ticked the content with the class `.check_box_notice_content` should show
- i really do not want use toggle, your advise would be much appreciated

html

```
<div class="notice_info">
  <%= f.input :neednotice, label: "Do you need to give notice?", id: "userj_neednotice" %>
  <div class='check_box_notice_content hide'>
    <%= f.association :category_notice, collection: CategoryNotice.all, prompt: "please choose", label: 'notice period' %>
    <%= f.text_field :stratdate, label: "when can you start?", class: "datepicker", placeholder: "when can you start work? select date" %>                
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#userj_neednotice").click(function () {
    $(".check_box_notice_content").removeClass("hide");
    if ($('.userj_neednotice').checked == true) {
      $(".check_box_notice_content").removeClass("hide");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/39/)**

You could create a function called for example `show_notice_if_checked` then call it on ready function (for case of refresh) and call it in `change` event (for case of check/uncheck) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function show_notice_if_checked(){
        if ( $("#userj_neednotice").is(":checked") ) {
            $(".check_box_notice_content").show();
        }
        else {
          $(".check_box_notice_content").hide();
        }
    }

    show_notice_if_checked(); //Case of refresh

    //Case of change
    $("#userj_neednotice").change(function () {
      show_notice_if_checked();
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

### Checked by default example

```js
function show_notice_if_checked(){
  if ( $("#userj_neednotice").is(":checked") ){
    $(".check_box_notice_content").show();
  }
  else {
    $(".check_box_notice_content").hide();
  }
}

show_notice_if_checked(); //Case of refresh

//Case of change
$("#userj_neednotice").change(function () {
  show_notice_if_checked();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="notice_info">
  <input type="checkbox" id="userj_neednotice" checked/>
  <div class='check_box_notice_content hide'>
    Notice text here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Zakaria Acharki i think your answer may be the best answer but it stating a syntax error on this line `if $("#userj_neednotice").is(":checked") {` tried correcting it but still getting an error

Comment: Fixed @ARTLoe just missing parenthese there should be `if ( $("#userj_neednotice").is(":checked") ) {`, updated my answer by adding working fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery also has a `toggleClass` option that you can provide a boolean (whether or not the checkbox is checked). First step is getting the `checked` value itself. As mentioned `$('#userj_neednotice')` returns a jquery collection. You can either get the property of the first item with `prop` or get the underlying vanilla object with `$('#userj_neednotice')[0].checked`

Combining that with [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/), you can hide or show the contents with:

```
   $(".check_box_notice_content").toggleClass("hide", !$('#userj_neednotice')[0].checked);
```

The above can be run on load (document ready) to show the contents, provided that the server controls if the checkbox is checked (otherwise you have to use cookies as Sebastian mentioned)

The checkbox change event can reuse the code if you put it in a function or it can use `this` to check the state:

```
$("#userj_neednotice").change(function () {
    $(".check_box_notice_content").toggleClass("hide", !this.checked);    
});
```

---

*edit* to give a short example of reusing the function which was mentioned above, both calls (onload and change) could be combined as follows:

```
function checkVisible(){
        $(".check_box_notice_content").toggle(this.checked==true); 
}

checkVisible.call($('#userj_neednotice').change(checkVisible)[0]);
```

Used toggle instead of toggleClass to show that toggle can also work with a boolean value, but if you prefer a class toggleClass can be used in the same manner.
[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9uuxgert/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) (Jquery 1.6+) to check the `checked` attribute, because you are using a class selector (this would return a set of elements, not just one).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#userj_neednotice").change(function () {
    if ($('.userj_neednotice').prop('checked')) {
      $(".check_box_notice_content").show();
    }
    else{
      $(".check_box_notice_content").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Notice that I also changed the event to `change` instead of `click`, since in my opinion would be more semantically correct.

Comment: thank you @sebastianb but when i refresh the page the content with the class `".check_box_notice_content"` is hidden. how do i get the content to still display when the page is refreshed and the box with the id `"#userj_neednotice"`  has been checked? - i need to add something like at the beginning of the but i am unsure `  if $(".check_box_notice_content").checked== true {
    $(".check_box_notice_content").show();
  }`

Comment: If what you want is to "remember" the state after a refresh, You'll need to use [cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599287/create-read-and-erase-cookies-with-jquery).