# how to prevent the previous submitted modal from popping out when hitting the back button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

the situation was like this. I have a bootstrap coded modal. When I click a submit button, it gets triggered and pop-out a box that has a yes or no plus input box in it. So either I click yes or no, it will just close the box. Some other pages also has this popup up. the problem is, after the modal closed down, when I clicked the back button, of the page, the modal also pops out when there's no javascript that triggers to fire it. the previous code of the back button was like

```
go.history(-1)
```

then I tried to changed it to

```
windows.history.back()
```

it didn't helped at all, it still pops out the modal . any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: I think the issue here is in the code that open the popup as it should prevent the default behaviour: reloading the page. You should call the *event.preventDefault()*, with *event* as the first parameter of the handler function.

Comment: but it's a bootstrap. I never and don't wish to modify the core javascript of bootstrap. all I know is, the data-target thing in the html code of the button is the one triggering the div id of the modal popup

Comment: please share some more code, like where you open the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You may set a cookie. When it exists, simply dont show your modal.

Here is an example:

*Note: I will use a snippet I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1599291/3435728).*

```
var cookieName = 'home_modal';
if(!readCookie(cookieName)){
    showModal();

    //the modal will not show up for 1 day
    createCookie(cookieName, 1, 1);
}

// #### [Base functions] ####

// Cookies
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";               

    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
}

function showModal() {
    //your modal logic goes here
}
```

Comment: any othe solutions or ideas ?

Comment: @sasori not ATM for pure javascript. But if your script is based on php, you can also set a [php session](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php) and create a javascript flag based on it and, again, if this flag value is set, dont call your _showModal()_ function

Comment: but unfortunately, the thing is in bootstrap, I'm not very good in html nor javascript nor css

Comment: Can you show us a piece of your "display modal" code? Or may be put a link??