# How can I get cookies in Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, cookies, userscripts

I'm writing a script using Tampermonkey. I need to somehow get the cookie value (with the session id) from the browser.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question it was marked as a duplicate of.  Specifically, this is for Tampermonkey.  The other question is for jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [COOKIE](https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) plugin.

To create a cookie:

```
$.cookie("example", "foo");
```

Get a cookie:

```
$.cookie("example")
```

Delete a cookie:

```
$.removeCookie("example");
```

as community wiki pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599287/create-read-and-erase-cookies-with-jquery).

To use that plugin in Tampermonkey, first you need to load jQuery and then add this plugin:

```
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
// @require https://raw.githubusercontent.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/master/src/js.cookie.js
```

Comment: But how to install it into Tampermonkey?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? You need jquery first to use that plugin. Also, I would recommend to edit your questions's title.

Comment: Yes, I'm using jQuery. And Tampermonkey.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: When I want to set that cookie as a var, i just go and use:
`var x = Cookies.get("y");`?

Comment: no you say $.cookie("example", "foo");

Comment: But I cannot create a session cookie on site i don't own by myself, or can I?

Comment: This syntax doesn't work anymore.  the api is Cookies  i.e.  Cookies.get()