# Set Cookie in C# and access in Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, cookies

I have to set a cookie in C# and access it in UI through jQuery. I need to access this cookie throughout the application. I'm able to see the cookie in chrome developer tool : Application - Storage - Cookies but if I try to access as `$.cookie("_MyCookie")` its undefined.

C#

```
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("_MyCookie") { Value = language });
```

jQuery

```
$.cookie("_MyCookie");
```

Comment: Follow following Link .. https://forums.asp.net/t/1635824.aspx?Set+cookie+with+JQuery+and+read+it+code+behind

Answer (score 0):

You can get the cookie value in Jquery but there should you need to specify Path parameter as base path like '/' and expire time after then you can get the value as you have mention above.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery Code

```
 <script>
        function ShowCookie() {
            var MyCookie = getCookieValue("MyCookieName");
            alert(MyCookie);
        }

        function getCookieValue(name) {
            cookieList = document.cookie.split('; ');
            cookies = {};
            for (i = cookieList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                cookie = cookieList[i].split('=');
                cookies[cookie[0]] = cookie[1];
            }
            return cookies[name];
        }
    </script>
```

C# Code

```
 Response.Cookies["MyCookieName"].Value = "CookieValue";
```

Comment: Thank you so much @konzo

Answer (score 0):

I think You are not plugin Jquery Cookie or if plugin then not valid path or something wrong in it.

[are you plugin Jquery Cookie?](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)
for example you can visit [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1599367/6294260)