# Run Only One Time Per Visit

Tags: jquery

I am very, very new at this.  What function and where do I place this function in the code below that will only run once per visit?

```
<script>
jQuery('.count').each (function () {
    jQuery(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: jQuery(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            jQuery(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated the answer. You can try to use session storage.

```
  if (!sessionStorage.firstVisit) {
        console.log('first time');
        //run your desired code here.

       sessionStorage.setItem("firstVisit", "1");
    }
```

Comment: Probably should be session storage, otherwise it will be once forever.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for mentioning. Am currently from a mobile device. So couldn't run this code. If there are any other corrections please make it.

Answer (score 0):

Took from here:
[#a/1599367/6687923](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1599367/6687923)

Include JQuery.Сookie Library (after include JQuery library):

```
<head>
// ...
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
// ... 
</head>
```

Use this script:

```
<script>
if(!$.cookie("firstVisit"){

    // first time code
    // ...

    // Create expiring cookie, 2 days from then:
    $.cookie("firstVisit", "1", { expires: 2 });
}
</script>
```