# Want to check a name & value of a cookie using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a cookie which has many name value pairs and I want to test for a name value pair. If it exists I need to display the name and the value. If the name value pair matches the variable I define, then the href value has to be updated throughout the page from say "http://www.google.com" to "http://test.com".

How I can get this done?

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie

Answer (score 0):

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95213/can-jquery-read-write-cookies-to-a-browser) will be helpful.