# JQuery set cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

How to save div title into cookies?  And how to get this saved data, back?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setcookie(title, value, exp) {
    var expdate = new Date();
    expdate.setDate(expdate.getDate() + exp);
    document.cookie = title+'='+value+';expires='+expdate.toGMTString()+';path=/';
}
</script>

<div title="1" onclick="setcookie();"></div>
```

Comment: Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95213/can-jquery-read-write-cookies-to-a-browser) question about jQuery and cookies. It will be easier to use a plug-in, like http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie.

Use following code to get the title of the div:

```
title = $("div").attr("title");
```

Comment: The link seems to be outdated! :(

Comment: @Nation I'm using it too. Pasted it on pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/GFvUTDV2

Comment: With jQuery, you can grab the title attribute on a click event.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [window.localStorage](http://blog.jbstrickler.com/2010/09/html5-localstorage/).  It's very effective for what you are looking to do.

```
//Save the data
window.localStorage['mydiv'] = $('div').attr('title');

//Retrieve the data
$('div').attr('title', window.localStorage['mydiv']);
```

Comment: As PoweRoy says, localstorage only works with the most up-to-date browsers. It's a great feature, but you need to check that your target audience will be able to use it before you commit to anything that new.