# Creating cookies through jquery

Tags: jquery, cookies

How can I create, delete, edit cookies using jQuery?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95213/can-jquery-read-write-cookies-to-a-browser

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery doesn't include cookie-specific functionality, but this jQuery plugin can simplify client-side cookie manipulation:

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 2):

Here is an nice jQuery plugin for handling cookies.

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2010/09/jquery-cookies-getsetdelete-plugin.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a JQuery plugin to these stuffs here: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie And, this is detailed notes for Cookie How-To in JQuery http://www.ilovecolors.com.ar/using-cookies-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie