# Set a jquery cookie on my fancybox onpage load

Tags: jquery, cookies, fancybox

this is what is used to load fancybox on page load. However, I want this to be appeared on new visitors or people who visited the page 3 days ago.

I guess with a jQuery cookie but I don't know how.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $.fancybox(
        '<h2>Hi!</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>',
        {
                'autoDimensions'    : false,
            'width'                 : 350,
            'height'                : 'auto',
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none'
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95213/can-jquery-read-write-cookies-to-a-browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `<head>` add `<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>`, then:

```
$(function() {
    if ($.cookie('mycookie')) {
        // it hasn't been three days yet
    } else {
        $.fancybox(
            '<h2>Hi!</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>',
            {
                'autoDimensions'    : false,
                'width'             : 350,
                'height'            : 'auto',
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none'
            }
        );
    }
});

// set cookie to expire in 3 days
$.cookie('mycookie', 'true', { expires: 3});
```

This uses the [cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) plugin.

Comment: mycookie is the name of the cookie right? If I visit the page having mycookie and then change the name of it will appear again ?

Comment: Yes, mycookie is the name of the cookie. If you change the name it will create a new cookie.

Comment: Can you please update your code with mine? I am having some difficulties. Thank you though, I have accepted your answer!

Answer (score 0):

See [Can jQuery read/write cookies to a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95213/can-jquery-read-write-cookies-to-a-browser)

Answer (score 0):

I have read this and tried to incorporate this to my website but its not working.

In my 'theme.liquid'

Under ''

I have this:

`<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>`

In my 'jquery.cookies.js'

I have:

```
$(function() {
    if ($.cookie('mycookie')) {

    } else {
        $.fancybox(
            '<script src="//setup.shopapps.io/social-login/script/snookieshop.js?width=300&height=330"></script>'
,
            {
                'autoDimensions'    : true,
                'width'             : 350,
                'height'            : 'auto',
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none'
            }
        );
    }
});

$.cookie('mycookie', 'true', { expires: 1});
```

The reason why I have this Script is because I am using a app from Shopify and this is the line of code they gave me for a sign up with social media.

`<script src="//setup.shopapps.io/social-login/script/snookieshop.js?width=300&height=330"></script>`

The purpose of doing this is because I want the pop-up screen to appear on the homepage whenever a customer comes in and visits.