# jQuery selector - code correctness question

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm new to jQuery. I'm trying to use this code:

```
var ThisTableWrapper = $('#switch1').parent().next();
var ThisTable = $(ThisTableWrapper > '.table-data');
```

But it doesn't seems to work.

What is the correct way to write that in one line?

I've tried something like this - but with no success

```
$( $('#switch1').parent().next();) > .table-data);
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

HTML HERE: [html code](http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/CHc6u/)

Comment: You should post the HTML code. No one can assume how your nested tags look like from a not working jacasript code, except some users with a huge reputation pool ;-)

Comment: Hi All, <html> is here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/CHc6u/)

Comment: I've updated your fiddle with some working pice of code. http://jsfiddle.net/CHc6u/41/

Comment: Thanks @DanielB - there is actually a bit more to it:)

Comment: I'm aware of that, but your fiddle did nothing ;-)

Comment: It was just a code example for you guys. Quick one -  why this small function of your stops working after 3rd or 4th change?

Comment: because it only adds classes ;-) it should remove the "old" ones as well ;-) major bug I think ;-)

Comment: But it does work when the class number has increase - e.g from table.s1 to table.s2? Why is that? CSS selectors always give more power to higher number or last added?

Comment: No, but the classes with the higher number are defined later in the CSS, so if applied, they override the previously applied styles. after selection all styles the table will look like `<table class="s1 s2 s3 s4">` and because `s4` is defined last, it will be applied. try to change the order in the css definition an you will see the last defined rule has the highest priority.

Comment: Here a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CHc6u/42/) with fix for that ;-)

Comment: .attr('class', '') - that is very clever! I've always used .removeAttr('class') and than define new one. Thanks for explanation regarding CSS!

Comment: @DanielB - do you know any simple way to save configuration made by jquery to cookie? So it would stay same next time you visit that page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95213/can-jquery-read-write-cookies-to-a-browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery selectors must always be **strings**, or other jQuery / DOM elements, but not a combination / concatenation of both.

The second line should be:

```
var ThisTable = ThisTableWrapper.children('.table-data');
```

Or in one line:

```
var ThisTable = $('#switch1').parent().next().children('.table-data');
```

The documentation provides a [list of possible selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).

---

As @DanielB points out in his comment, this is just to fix the *syntax*, it does not mean that the correct elements are selected. This depends on your actual HTML which you did not post.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're just trying to use the child css selector

```
var ThisTableWrapper = $('#switch1').parent().next();
var ThisTable = ThisTableWrapper.children('.table-data');
```

If you want it in one line, just chain it

```
var ThisTable = $('#switch1').parent().next().children('.table-data');
```

http://api.jquery.com/children

I've edited the answer to use `children()` instead of `find()`. Use `find()` if you want to go more than one level deep (like in Inception!)

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
var ThisTableWrapper = $('#switch1').parent().next().children('.table-data');
```

Unless the .table-data isn't a direct child then

```
var ThisTableWrapper = $('#switch1').parent().next().find('.table-data');
```