# Server-Side JavaScript: HTTP GET with cookie?

Tags: javascript, unix, curl, xmlhttprequest, system

I have a UI Automation script, written in JavaScript. From that script, how do I execute a `GET` request to a URL with a cookie? E.g:

```
curl "https://example.com/path?a=123&b=cool" --cookie "c=12"
```

Or, if you know how to run system commands from JavaScript, like you can do in Ruby, that'll work too.

Comment: For those who do not know the curl command-line options by heart, an explanation what your curl call actually does would be nice. ;)

Comment: `man curl`. Then, type `/` to search. Then, type `-b` and hit enter. You will see: `-b/--cookie <name=data> (HTTP) Pass  the  data to the HTTP server as a cookie`. I updated the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking out [HTTP GET request in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript/4033310#4033310) and reading step 7 of ["3.6.2. The setRequestHeader() method" in the W3C specs for XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method), I came up with:

```
function httpGet(url, opts={}) {
  var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
  client.open('GET', url, false); // not async
  if (opts.cookie) {
    client.setRequestHeader('Cookie', opts.cookie);
  }
  client.send();
}
```

FYI, I'm disregarding the response because I'm deleting a resource (perhaps I should verify the correct response so that I know the resource was deleted). So, yes, this should be a DELETE request, but they configured the server to accept a GET request, and I have no control over this.

Answer (score 1):

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95213/can-jquery-read-write-cookies-to-a-browser) on using jQuery to set cookies in the browser.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure how that thread is relevant. I'm asking how to send a GET request with a cookie to a URL with JavaScript. And, the JavaScript is being run by [Mac Developer Tools : Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/), not by a browser.