# persisting or set checked radiobutton as checked even after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have 4 radio buttons and a textbox and a search button. User selects a radiobtn, types in keyword and clicks Search. OnClick of button, the radiobutton value and inputbox value is grabbed and passed to the URL as querystring. Like this http://mysite.com/event.aspx?kwd=keyword&type=radiobtnvalue
If user selects Event, types in 'Dance' and hits SearchButton it would  go to http://mysite.com/event.aspx?kwd=Dance&type=Event and refresh the page and once the page is refreshed it will reset the default 'checked' back to 'All'. I want to maintain the user checked radio's checked state even after refresh. Is it possible? using some form of jquery?
    Basically the logic is like this, if Page URL is mysite.com/event.aspx, default checked radioBtn is "All" else whatever user selected and passed to the URL as querystring

```
<div class="EventRadios" style="color:#574319; font:13px Trebuchet">
    <input type="radio" name="EventType" value="" checked="checked"/>All &nbsp;  
    <input type="radio" name="EventType" value="Classes" />Class &nbsp;  
    <input type="radio" name="EventType" value="Events" />Event &nbsp;    
    <input type="radio" name="EventType" value="Support Groups" />Support Group&nbsp;&nbsp;<br /><br />
</div>
<input name="KeywordBox" class="BasicSearchInputBox" type="text" value="Keyword Search..."/>
<div class="searchBtnHolder"><a class="searchButton" href="#" type="submit"><span>Search</span></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can store the value in [cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95213/can-jquery-read-write-cookies-to-a-browser) or as an alternative can use [`sessionStorage`](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/domstorage.shtml)

Comment: I think a session would work better as a user can elect to block cookies