# Reveal Modal - Show only once per day

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using reveal modal to load a popup when my website loads. However the popup loads everytime the page loads. Since a visitor can visit multiple pages or on multiple instances, this limitation is turning out to be bad for our visitors experience.

The following is the js I am using to load the reveal modal once a page is loaded.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
/* Pop-up
================================================= */

$(function() {
    function showpanel() {
    $('.reveal-modal').reveal({
        animation: 'fade',
        animationspeed: 800
    });
    }
    setTimeout(showpanel, 4000)
   }); 
});
```

What can I add to ensure that the the reveal modal loads only once in a particular day no matter how many different pages a visitor accesses?

Would appreciate any assistance.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve this is with a [cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95213/can-jquery-read-write-cookies-to-a-browser) which only lasts 24 hours.

What you'd do is check if there was a cookie and show the dialog if there isn't

```
if($.cookie('MyCookie') != 'DialogShown'){
  showpanel();
  setCookie();
}
```

Here's the code to set it

```
function setCookie(){
    $.cookie('MyCookie', 'DialogShown',
      {
         expires: date.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) // now add 24 hours
      });
}
```

However be aware the user may have configured their browser to reject cookies and in the UK (and probably other countries there are [regulations](http://ico.org.uk/for_organisations/privacy_and_electronic_communications/the_guide/cookies) about websites using cookies).

Comment: Hi Liath,
Thanks for your response. However, can you please assist with showing me how to implement your code into my code above. I am relatively new to this.

Comment: I've expanded my answer

Answer (score 2):

You'll need persistent storage, as in cookies, localStorage or serverside storage.

```
$(function() {
    if ( localStorage.getItem('seen') != (new Date()).getDate()) {
        setTimeout(showpanel, 4000);
    }
});


function showpanel() {
    $('.reveal-modal').reveal({
        animation: 'fade',
        animationspeed: 800
    });

    localStorage.setItem('seen', (new Date()).getDate());
}
```

There's a polyfill for older browsers at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

Comment: Nice approach and certainly gets around the issues with cookies! May have issues with older browsers...

Comment: @adeno, I've tried to implement the script but it wouldn't work for some reason. The popup keeps on re appearing each time a page of the website is loaded. My implementation was as follows:

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
/* Pop-up
================================================= */

$(function() {
    if ( localStorage.getItem('seen') != (new Date()).getDate()) {
        setTimeout(showpanel, 4000);
    }
});


function showpanel() {
    $('.reveal-modal').reveal({
        animation: 'fade',
        animationspeed: 800
    });
    localStorage.setItem('seen', (new Date()).getDate());
}

Comment: Works just fine for me, here's a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ysURj/), the alert only pops up once.

Answer (score 1):

For Client side solution you may use cookie to set in user's browser and set it's expiry for 1 day.

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 1 });
```

For more details see:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

EDIT:

Include Jquery-cookie Plugin in your html page and then add following piece of code

```
$(function() {
    if($.cookie('alreadyShow') === null) {
        $.cookie('alreadyShow', true, {expires: 1});

        $('.reveal-modal').reveal({
           animation: 'fade',
           animationspeed: 800
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks.
Because I am relatively a rookie in web programming, would really appreciate if you can help me implementing your suggestion into my code above.