# jquery set cookie without plugin

Tags: jquery, cookies

Most of the answers I've checked suggest using a plugin, but to save me editing 100+ pages of my site by adding a plugin URL into the headers, I'm asking if it's possible to do the following without a plugin...

I have a menu with several submenus that are toggled to show/hide using jquery. I want to save a cookie so the menu status is saved between page loads.

Current code example:

```
$('#heading1').click(function() {
$('#menu1').toggle( "fast" );
});

$('#heading2').click(function() {
$('#menu2').toggle( "fast" );
});
```

If it's not possible/easy then I'll go for the plugin

Comment: Your 100+ pages of your site should share a common header (template). Regarding your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can also just past the plugin code above these lines? Or at the bottom of that file. Because the plugin is nothing more than a few lines of code. You can make it custom but than you are spending more time.

Add the plugin to the top of the file. And use cookies.

Comment: Cool, will go for that then

Answer (score 0):

The default JavaScript "API" for setting a cookie is as easy as:

`document.cookie = 'mycookie=valueOfCookie;expires=DateHere;path=/'`

Find [a link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95213/can-jquery-read-write-cookies-to-a-browser#answer-2210411)